# Writing IAR output to ARM chips without IAR

Tags: arm, embedded, iar, segger-jlink

We currently hold a full license for the IAR EWARM IDE but we need to upload firmware to units being made meaning only one person can do the uploading as the application is way over the kickstart size.

I'm wondering if there is an alternative method for just uploading (no debugging) IAR's outputted executable without the need for a fully licensed version? I've looked into the Eclipse plugin but this seems to rely on the IAR compiler still.

We're using the TMS470 chip and a JLink programmer.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Presumably if you can get the output in some standard form like a hex file or a flat binary, then you can use any generic programmer tool compatible with your interface pod; that said the jlink hardware pods tend to be a pain to work with since they put more effort into locking down their software than making their product actually work.

Comment: I think jlink is supported by openocd, which is free, likewise there are many inexpensive jtag wigglers out there, or just roll your own from an ftdi ft2232 mini module and a few wires, about $20 (then use openocd).  At least for debugging, writing to flash is more and more vendor specific and may not be supported by openocd or other software, generally though you should not have to use a developers license to do mass programming of parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project options, there is a category for Output Converter. In this section you can get a Motorola S-record format, Intel hex format, binary, or other output type. From here, you can use the J-Link software, though you will need to purchase a license to be able to download arbitrary code not as a part of the debug process.

J-Flash is the software component needed for stand-alone flashing support: [J-Flash order page.](http://shop-us.segger.com/J_Flash_p/8.08.02.htm)

Answer (score 2):

[J-Flash](http://www.segger.com/jflash.html) licences are locked the the hardware serial number - you will need one for each J-Link you want to use.  They are [somewhat expensive](http://www.segger.com/pricelist-j-link-related.html) for an existing J-Link.

[OpenOCD](http://openocd.sourceforge.net/) includes support for Segger J-Link (which IAR rebadge), and can be used a for [stand-alone flash programming](https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/JTAG/_resources/Manual_PROGRAMMER.pdf)but whether it works apparently depends on the J-Link firmware version, so YMMV.

There are [lower cost JTAG debugger/programmers](https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/JTAG/ARM-USB-TINY-H/)(example) that will work reliably with OpenOCD and cost much less that a single J-Link licence.

Answer (score 1):

Segger offers [J-Flash](http://www.segger.com/jflash.html), a PC software program that interfaces with the J-Link debug probe to program the flash memory on a target.  You need a license for J-Flash but it's independent of the IAR (or other) toolchain.

You might need another software program to convert IAR's standard executable output format to a format that J-Flash can use, perhaps hex, s-record, or binary.  IAR probably includes the conversion tool or you may be able to do a web search for something.